# Эластичный макет

Tags: html, css

Привет.

В рамках изучения данной темы хочется увидеть готовый шаблон макета. 
Практика без теории ничто.

Подскажите ресурс, на котором можно скачать данный макет.

Благодарен.

Comment: Используйте Бутстрап или другой фреймворк.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety

Здесь посмотрите описание и примеры.

Answer (score 2):

Сохраняешь на ПК любой "резиновый" сайт и копаешься, меняешь тексты, стили, пытаешься изменить страницу.

Comment: резиновый не есть эластичный....

Comment: Ну, найди эластичный сайт. Разницы в методе освоения материана нет.